# How to set different index pages depending on logged in users role in yii

Tags: php, yii, roles, rbac

I am working on one yii project. I have used RBAC module in that for user management. My user roles are like **Admin**, **Superadmin**, **sales**, **Authenticated**, **Customer**.

I want to redirect users as per their roles after logging in. For example, Admin and Superadmin should see page1 as index page (default action) after they login and customer should see page2 as index page (default action) after they login. I have set the menu depending upon user roles i.e. which menu tabs should be visible to whom.

Also I am aware about setting default action in yii. i.e. in main.php file, we have to set default controller action. But I don't understand how can i solve this problem. Please help me for this.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to just check if REQUEST_URI is / and redirect to appropriate controller and action based on role.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing this:
In my index action of site controller, I put following logic..

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $getroles=Rights::getAssignedRoles(Yii::app()->user->Id);
                    foreach($getroles as $getrole){

                      $getallroles[] = $getrole->name; 
                    }
                    $count_roles = sizeof(array_intersect(array('admin', 'SuperAdmin', 'Sales'), $getallroles));
                    $count_roles1 = sizeof(array_intersect(array('customer'), $getallroles));


    if($count_roles1){
        $this->redirect(array('CategoryImages/showGallery')); 
    }
    else{
        $this->redirect(array('Category/admin')); 

    }
}
```

**Its working as required.**